# Drop databag on node as is (json files in a dir)

Tags: chef-infra

Say I have this chef data bag:

```
- data_bags
    -  things
        -  alpha.json
        -  bravo.json
        -  charlie.json
```

How can I drop the `things` data bag as is (a dir with three json files) into `/tmp/things` on a node using a recipe? Currently I am iterating over the `things` data bag with `.each`, reading each data bag item and then writing a json file from the returned hash. This seems silly, is there a builtin chef utility that can just drop a data bag as is onto a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that would be the way to do it. You could use the `search(:things, '*:*')` to save a few API calls but the code structure would be the same. Bags are generally used to configure recipe code, not written to files, so there is nothing specifically for this. If you want to copy data verbatim to the file system, put it under `files/` in a cookbook and use a `remote_directory` resource.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yea this is kind of a strange use case (as seems to happen a lot with chef).